# FFMPEG join multiple video lost audio

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to join 2-3 videos it's working when all video has audio or without audio...

> Command=  "-f concat -i files.txt -codec copy output.mp4"

File.txt

> file '0.mp4'
>
> file '1.mp4'
>
> file '2.mp4'

Now the issue is when 0.mp4 is without audio and 1.mp4 is with audio and when i join these videos full audio lost in output.. output will be without audio.

I want this join with all as it is like if 0.mp4 without audio then audio will not play for this and 1.mp4 play audio should play...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the answer.. need to first add silent audio in video files that don't have audio

> ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -i 0.mp4 -shortest -c:v copy -c:a aac new_0.mp4
>
> From here I concatenate as I did before, but replacing "0.mp4" in
>    File.txt with "new_0.mp4"

File.txt

> file 'new_0.mp4'
>
> file '1.mp4'
>
> file '2.mp4'
>
> Command= "-f concat -i files.txt -codec copy output.mp4"